# How to import class in android studio

Tags: java, android

Hi How to import class G to MainActivity

For example : in Main Avtivity I have edit text I wont if I write SUN show me a toast , but I wont to cods for toast written in Class G
How can I do that?

Comment: Is the user clicking a button to go from MainActivity to class G? I'm guessing class G is another activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You transfer information from one activity to another by using Intent.
You need to get the text from the edittext...

```
String textFromEditText = editText.getText();
```

Then create an intent to use it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityG.class);
intent.putExtra("message", textFromEditText);
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside of your ActivityG

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message");
```

Create your toast in ActivityG.

```
Toast.makeText(ActivitiyG.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function in class G that displays a toast, you can either:

1. Make it static and refer to it directly

   ```
   public static void displayToast() {
   //create toast
   }
   ```

   and then

   ```
   G.displayToast();
   ```
2. Create an object of the class, and then call the function

   ```
   G exampleObject = new G();
   G.displayToast();
   ```